# VBAは二重ループがつかえないのでしょうか？

Tags: vba

taguti 52
のように名前を１列目、スコアを2列目にしました。一応できたのですがnext縛りというかなんというか、for文で数字だけとって、foreachで要素をとりたかったです。

```vb
sub name_score()
  dim names as variant
  names = array("taguti", "fkoji", "sugimoto", "tanaka", "higasi", "sajio", "kojima", "midori", "kobayasi")
  dim scores as variant
  scores = array(52,82,99,32,48,62,72,58,59)
  for i = 0 to 8
    cells(i + 1, 1).value = names(i)
    cells(i + 1, 2).value = scores(i)
  next i
end sub
```

```py
###pythonのイメージ###
for i in range(1, 9):
    for name in names:
        cells(i, 1).value = name
```

pythonみたいな二重ループはVBAではできないのでしょうか？

Comment: ご提示頂いた Python のコードだと (1, 1), (2, 1), …, (9, 1) のセルにはどれも `names` の最後の要素である `"kobayasi"` が代入されることになると思います。これは意図とあっていますか？　このコードはそもそも二重ループで表すべきものではないのではないかと疑っています。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。「最後にkobayasiが代入される」ために二重ループが完成しないので、VBAにはなにかいいやり方があるだろうかと疑問になり質問しました。　別段二重ループを使用する必要はたしかにありません。

Comment: 単刀直入に言いますとVBAではNEXTがあるために二重ループは使えないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA でも二重ループは使えます。

誤解なさっている点が複数ありそうなので、1つずつ説明します。

### For...Next ループは二重にできる

For...Next ループで使うカウンタの名前を変えれば、ループをネストさせることができます。
以下のコードは、九九表を作ります。

```vb
Sub Main
  For i = 1 To 9
    For j = 1 To 9
      Cells(i, j).Value = i * j
    Next j
  Next i
End Sub
```

### VBA にも foreach ループはある

For Each...Next ステートメントを使えば foreach ループができます。
以下のコードは、配列 `rows` に格納された整数 `row` に対して、A 列 `row` 行のセルの内容を `"XXX"` にします。

```vb
Sub Main
  Dim rows(5) As Integer
  rows = Array(3, 9, 2, 8, 5)
  For Each row In rows
    Cells(row, 1).Value = "XXX"
  Next row
End Sub
```

### ループの種類が違ってもネストできる

他のプログラミング言語と同じように、For...Next ループの中に For Each...Next ループを入れ子にしたりできます。

### 質問文中のプログラムで実装しようとしている動作は、一重ループで書くべき

ご質問のプログラムで実装しようとなさっている動作は「長さが同じ2つの一次元配列 `names`, `scores` が与えられる。`names` の内容を A 列に、`scores` の内容を B 列に展開せよ」ということだと思います。

これは一次元データを一次元的に扱えば解決できる内容なので、ネストの無いループで実現できますし、そうすべきです。

**補足**: もし `names` の長さが分からないということであれば、For Each...Next ループを使う際にカウンタ変数を作ってあげれば良いと思います。

```vb
Sub Main
  Dim names() As Integer
  ReDim names(5)
  names = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
  Dim i As Integer
  i = 1
  For Each name In names
    Cells(i, 1).Value = name
    i = i + 1
  Next name
End Sub
```

Comment: しょうもない質問をして申し訳ありません。考えていたら、「このループは二重にするべきではない」ということでなんとなくわかってきたのですが、pythonコードも二番目のループを全部終えてから、次がはじまるというので、VBAもなんらかわりなかったですね。この質問はpythonの二重ループの誤解です。すいませんでした。